# How to delete a key if key has a value

Tags: redis

I use Redis. I want to delete a key key1 if it has the value value1.
I have find this command :

```
DEL key1
```

but not :

```
DEL key1 value1
```

Comment: You'd have to check and delete.

Answer (score 1):

Redis doesn't have an atomic command for this, but you can build it yourself.

The simplest case would be to `GET` followed by `DEL`, but it introduces a race condition if another connection changes `key1` between the two commands:

```
GET key1

# then, if it matches the value you care about:
DEL key1
```

If you can use Lua scripting, then you can do it in one Redis command:

```
EVAL "if redis.call('get', KEYS[1]) == ARGV[1] then redis.call('del', KEYS[1]) end" 1 key1 value1
```

If you can't use Lua scripting, then you can use [transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions), but it will take multiple commands:

```
WATCH key1
GET key1

# if the value matches (the EXEC call will fail if anything changed key1):
MULTI
DEL key1
EXEC

# if it doesn't:
UNWATCH key1
```